# Resource Folder Xcode 4, how to delete files from package

Tags: iphone, path

1. I am using Xcode 4. I have copied
   several images to main folder, I
   have built project, next I have
   deleted all images. When I list
   resources path by NSLog, I can see
   that there are still in this
   package. I've deleted build folder,
   clean etc. What should I do to
   delete this files from my package
2. And second question. Why when I copy
   an entire folder, and list files and
   directories by:

   ```
   NSFileManager *fm = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
   NSString *string = [[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath];
   for(NSString *name in [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:string error:nil])
   {
   NSLog(@"%@", name);
   }
   ```

In console a can only see files from this folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you deleted the project from simulator ? You can do it in the Simulator app or deleting the project folder at **~/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/**